# Individually add each entry in a list to a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Nums = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

print(str('\n'.join(Nums)) + 'XXX')
```

Currently this returns

```
1
2
3
4XXX
```

I'd like to get the code to return `xxx` after each number rather than after only the last! Is there a way to process each one of these individually so it prints each entry in `Nums + XXX`?

Example:

```
1XXX

2XXX
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Note, you don't have to call `str()` on the result of `.join`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [1]: Nums = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

In [2]: print('\n'.join([i+'XXX' for i in Nums]))
1XXX
2XXX
3XXX
4XXX
```

To print each line separately:

```
In [5]: for i in Nums:
   ...:     print('{}XXX\n'.format(i))
   ...:
1XXX

2XXX

3XXX

4XXX
```

Comment: While this is definitely close to what I'm asking for, is there a way to print each line/`#XXX` individually? This way you can add each result to a list like `Nums`

Comment: sure, I'll add a modification shortly.

Comment: Works flawlessly! Do you know where I can find the documentation for your solution? I'm fairly new to Python and would like to learn as much as I can before coming here for help

Comment: Glad it worked! You can follow this `https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/join` or some other good tutorials on string join method.

Answer (score 2):

It's similar to what you did with a small modification.

```
Nums = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

print('XXX\n'.join(Nums) + 'XXX\n')
```

I hope this helps!.